# How can i use created object in few routers?

Tags: node.js

I try to bind it to request.session or request.user, but have same error - 'undefined function'. How can i use created req.session.idle = new SteamIdle('user', 'pass') in /start router in /stop router, if i access them directly by url (localhost:3000/start and localhost:3000/stop)?

```
router.get('/start', checkAuth, function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var data = {
        statusCode: 1,
        status: 'connected'
    };

    if (typeof req.session.idle == "undefined")
        req.session.idle = new SteamIdle('user', 'pass'); // created instance

    if (!req.session.idle.isLogin){
        req.session.idle.connect();
        // req.session.idle.disconnect(); this will work here, but not in /stop router
    }
    res.send(data);
});

router.get('/stop', checkAuth, function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var data = {
        status: 'done'
    };

    if (typeof req.session.idle != "undefined"){
        req.session.idle.disconnect(); //undefined function, is there any way to make it work?
        delete req.session.idle;
    }
    res.send(data);
});
```

**SteamIdle**

```
function SteamIdle(user, pass){
    var self = this;

    self.userName = user;
    self.password = pass;

    // Main func
    self.disconnect = function() {
        console.log('disconnect');
    }

    self.connect = function(auth){
        console.log('start work for user ' + self.userName);
    }
}

module.exports = SteamIdle;
```

Comment: how will it go from /start to /stop route(i don't see next() in ur code and routes won't match anyway) or do u expect to use it in next req ? In that case node creates new req & res objects so u cant' use this approach to bind to req, u vl have to go through db

Comment: I just go like this - http://localhost:3000/start, http://localhost:3000/stop. I can save my vars at user request, but i can't save instance of object?

Comment: sry misunderstood ur que

Comment: @SLI what is it you need to share between connect and disconnect you can't save to session? I mean if connect function returns some identifier for current connection then save it to session and in stop route get it back from session and use it in your disconnect function

Comment: I try to do it, but it's just don't work like that. I don't know why. I can store some var and it's works, but if i store object with functions it's just don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I use express framework for nodejs. In [Express API](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) - i found app.locals propertis that has global scope. So i creat req.app.idle = new SteamIdle('user', 'pass') object and can access it's disconnect function at /stop router.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, r u trying to send request from chrome or some browser , issue is they send req twice (other to get favicon which messes up ur session object)

Try it from some `rest client` like postman , it `vl work`

In ur code i used `req.session.idle = {'a':'1'}` and able to get this json in stop route using postman

Comment: That's the point. I can get it to, but if i creat a instance of object SteamIdle. Than i can't use SteamIdle funcs in stop route. It has connect and disconnect function and they only work in route where i created SteamIdle.

Comment: may be steamIdle is creating some objects and not binding them to session , point me to a link to SteamIdle

Comment: can't figure out exactly but seems like u need to use bind , search javascript bind, vl look into it , by the time u may try on ur own